# If Kundalini awakening is the most potent form of Yoga and requires intense sadhana, what is this ‘westernised version’ being followed by just anyone?

Tags: shiva, guru, devi, chakras, kundalini

This is rather a confusing stance for me. It’s usually said Kundalini awakening needs proper receptivity and grace, guru initiation is one out of the many necessary methods to reach there and Kundalini is literally a goddess, but formless as we discuss here. What is this Chakra activation performed usually I see so many around doing then and activating, some Hindu spiritualists sharing too? People are making lot use of it for heightened intuition and consciousness, but I don’t see the intensity of its effects as usually mentioned popularly, for example burning illusions, powers, Samadhi as we take realized divine ones and scriptures in account etc. if it makes sense as well. people don’t experience side effects and balance them greatly usually said around, whatever is this then and can we equate it to putting in use then, we don’t need any Guru but just us? Kindly explain about this.

Comment: what they're doing is just one of the 8 steps of ashtanga yoga - namely Asana. Because it is simple and doesn't require any rules/regluations. For e.g. Yama (major rules) & Niyama (minor rules) are the first 2 steps. Even doing Niyama is almost impossible for most westerners.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE! Kindly have a look at the [HSE HELP CENTER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help), **specifically** the [How does New User get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se) and also, [HSE FAQ INDEX](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange). Please go through them and get started in here properly. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: Forceful Kundalini activation is dangerous. It has a similar effect as showing adult content to a nascent teen. People can go insane or can have twisted energies. Hence the need for a Guru. That said, the degree of activity of chakras is a barometer of spiritual maturity of a person (if awakened naturally). And, Siddhis are best avoided in spiritual pursuit unless one wants to spend time loitering around. They are far more addictive than dope. (Imagine quitting coffee!) So for one aimed at finding their real Self, remaining focused only on it is the best way forward. Lastly - Guru is within!!!